# Excel - Column Width does not match multiple added up

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm using the c# Excel Interop and attempting to make a merged cell's height fit to its contents. Autofit on merged cells cannot be done for some reason so I'm doing it with the following method

```
private void AutoFitAndMerge(Range toMerge, Range contentCell) {
    // Get Width of entire Merged Cell
    double width = 0.0;
    foreach (Range col in toMerge.Columns) {
        width += col.ColumnWidth;
    }

    // mimic merged cell with regular cell
    var cellWidth = contentCell.ColumnWidth;
    contentCell.ColumnWidth = width;
    contentCell.WrapText = true;

    // autofit the regular cell and copy that to merged
    contentCell.Rows.AutoFit();
    var wantedHeight = contentCell.RowHeight;

    // set it back
    contentCell.ColumnWidth = cellWidth;

    toMerge.Merge();
    toMerge.WrapText = true;
    toMerge.RowHeight = wantedHeight;
}
```

This works fine apart from in the beginning, when I set the contentCell's Width to the merged cells total width, it does not add up correctly.
The problem is that the contentCell ends up being slightly smaller causing the content to sometimes wrap around once more, and allocating too much space for the merged cell.

This also happens in excel when you add up 2 or more column widths and assign it to a cell as width, it ends up being slightly smaller.
Do the cells have some sort of padding/margin and how do I take that into account?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding the following code after the width calculation:

```
// excel has some cell padding or whatever? This is a workaround for it
width += .514 * ((toMerge.Columns.Count-1) * 2);
```

It's a hack but it meets my demands and works for me. What it's doing is basically assuming there is a padding of sorts on all cells of a certain value and adding that to the total.

Not accepting this as the answer since well, it isn't.